# Cube to count number of Customers for a given period

Tags: database-design, ssas, data-warehouse, cube

Today we have a dimension called Customer.

We have several SCD2 attributes so there is DateFrom and DateTo columns to indicate during what perid the record was active. We also have a CreationDate when the customer was created and a RemoveDate when the customer was removed.

Now I want to create a cube that in excel can show the number of unique customers for a given period. Say for example that I for each month want to show the number of customers that were not removed. In excel it could look like this

```
2013-01     2013-02     2013-03
100         120         80
```

2013-02 we had a total of 120 customers. This does not mean that we got 20 new customers from 2013-01 since we may have lost a couple of customers. Maybe we got 30 new and lost 10.

How can this be done?
All examples that I have read show a connection to a fact table for sales. But I want to know the number of customers. I think I managed to solve some of the problem by using a factless fact table and using a measure of count(distinct CustomerId). But that only gives the possibility to split the total number of customers. I want to see the number of customers for each month. So I believe I need to connect the Date-dimension in some way. But I cannot connect it with either creationdate or removedate since then it will only be counted for that specific day.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems pretty straightforward... create an aggregate fact table, that only records the "first" transaction of a given customer for whatever time period you want to track. I'm assuming your sales fact table has the date of the sale?

A customer SCD's dates shouldn't have anything to do with the sale dates...

```
AGG_CUSTOMER_SHOP
------------------------
MONTH_NUMBER INTEGER
CUSTOMER_ID INTEGER
```

Your ETL process that builds this by doing something like

```
SELECT distinct month_number, customer_id 
  FROM fact_sales s 
  JOIN dim_date d on (s.date_id = d.date_id)
  JOIN dim_customer c on (c.customer_id = s.customer_id)
```

Your date dim gets you the month number (201301) or whatever, and you just store that on your aggregate table.